# How can I prevent Node.js from garbage collecting (GC) a critical variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, garbage-collection

The property of a variable is purged in Node.js during garbage collection. However, I don't want this to happen. I have found solutions for it, such as saving a variable to a database or file. However, I don't like that approach. I just need a critical section or critical variable protected from garbage collection.

For instance, with the following code:

```
function a() {
  var b; 
}

c = new a();
```

How can I protect variable `c` from garbage collection?

After time goes by, `c.b` or `c` is deleted... In my case, `c.b` is deleted...

Please help me... I know my english is very poor, but I need your assistance so much.

Comment: What problem you trying to solve?.. If you want something not to be garbage collected, just add it to some global.

Comment: Really? However, in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202576/node-js-global-variable-property-is-purged, his variable was purged.

Comment: Yes, really.  Not sure what problem that person was having with his global going missing, it's certainly not how node.js works,.. I have websites / webapps that have global's that are loaded at startup and never change, and they exists for weeks / months..

Comment: Saying all this, I don't use the global object for storing global's,  I find it more structured to use another module.   For example I might have a unit call init.js.  I then require this from everywhere I need the global's from this.

Comment: Oh really? If your assistance is true, I think that that article is too old and node.js was updated. Thank you!!! I'm going to try it! Thank you very much~~!!!!!!

Comment: Do you mean that I should make another source code for initiating variable? Should I need to create the source code for initiating variable and require it? Using global?

Comment: Even simpler than that..  If say you wanted an application specific global object, you could maybe call it  `app-global.js` this file might be as simple as `module.exports = {}`,  in another module you could even do something like   `require('app-global').stayForever = 'This won't get garbage collected';`  Any other  module that then requires `app-global` will be able to access stayForever until application closes.  One note, especially for windows users, make sure the filename case is the same, as if you did `require('app-Global')`, this would give you another instance.

Comment: The above warning, is a good reason to always use lowercase for module names..

Comment: Oh thank you, in fact, I usually used variable name mixed case(lowercase, uppercase). I will try to use only lowercase variable name. Your assistance is very helpful :) One more time, thank you !!

Comment: In fact, I have one more question... Above question you can see, Last sentence "If I want to purge c.d, What do I need? Just delete c.d?" is right? 
If I want to delete some attribute in variable from memory, should I use just command 'delete'? Is it right?

Comment: No problem..  Just a note mixed case variables are fine.  It was the module name only this problem comes up, and it's only because windows has a case-insensitive file system.  IOW:  you can do  `var appGlobal = require('app-global')`,  it's just the bits in the quotes that needs to keep lowercase.

Comment: Yes, delete is the way,.  The Garbage collection is then free to do it's stuff.   You would only need to delete a root object too, as the GC will handle everything else..  eg. in your example, something like ->  `delete appGlobal.c;` would be all you need, no need to delete b, & d.  And you could of course just delete `d` by doing  `delete appGlobal.c.d;`

Comment: Oh really thanks! If I can provide you with prize, I will do that. Thanks!! I understand your answer! However, in testing your answer, I have a question. In my case, Should I need to export only "variable c" in my question example? Or I have to export "function a"? I think, in app-global, that I should export only "variable c". And then, I require only "variable c" and set "variable c" to "function c". For example, require('app-global').c = new a(); Is it right?

Comment: Yes, what you have done should be fine.  You don't need to export `a` because c, is an instance of a.  You would only need to export `a` as well if you wanted to create another instance.  So if `c` is a singleton this is the way to do it.

Comment: Omg! Your answer is always perfect to me because I should make many variable of "function a". I think the solution is creating another function included "function c". Is it right? Or is there another solution? For example, function bb() {
   this.child = {};
   function a() {
     var b;
   }
   bb.prototype.bb_init = function( name ) {
     this.child[name] = new a();
   }
}
temp = new bb();
temp.bb_init("hi");

Comment: Oh I got it! In exporting area, I should just create array and export array for many variable! Isn't it ? Yeah~~~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to note, in your code b and d are not properties on a.  They are local variables to the scope inside of the function a, which are not used, thus get cleaned up.

If you change it to:

```
function a() {
  this.b = 1;
  this.d = 2;
}

var c = new a();

console.log(c.b) //1
console.log(c.d) //2
```

You can then reference c.b and c.d and as long as you have a reference to c, it should not get collected.  Also if you have it as var b, d;  you cannot reference those from outside of the function.

compare to:

```
function a() {
  var b = 1;
  var d = 2;
}

var c = new a();

console.log(c.b) //undefined
console.log(c.d) //undefined
```

Comment: Oh really thanks! I couldn't think that. In my case, I declare init function in "function a". So it is done well. However, by your opinion, I understand why another variables, which are not used in init function, are noticed as "undefined". Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but you don't specify any scope for variable c. This would get c into the most upper scope and prevent it from getting removed by the garbage collector.

You can define c in current scope:

```
let c;
function doSomething() {
   c = {b: 1, d: 2};
}

doSomething();
```

Comment: Oh thank you. Is your opinion is similar to reply in a body text? Do you mean I need to declare the variable using 'global' or 'let'? However, in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202576/node-js-global-variable-property-is-purged, his variable was purged.